# what is the correct way to pass a range of values using "routing table" url format

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am learning ASP.NET MVC and it is easy to pass a single value to a view, 
using the following url format:

controller/view/**id**

and in the controller's code, I can simply define the integer id parameter as below:

```
ActionResult View(int? id)
{
}
```

but what is the accepted programming pattern (in ASP.NET MVC) to pass a range of values

controller/view/**id1-id2**

and how would the View method (in codebehind) would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly it's

```
controller/action/some-url-segment
```

Views are but the presentation logic that an action method with a view result returns, typically passing the view a model.

Secondly: There are no code-bind files for ASP.NET MVC Views, this is not web forms.

A possible route on the server side may be defined as follows:

```
url: "{controller}/{action}/page-{pagenum}"
```

And this would catch any url such as `/admin/getuserlist/page-5`

And an action method would receive those url segment params too.

```
ActionResult GetUserList(int pagenum)
```

The above gets ActionMethod parameter values from URL segments defined in the route.

You could also pass such values via query string:

```
/Admin/getuserlist?page=3&pagesize=45
```

You do not need to modify routes when using query string to pass values.

and a route such as `url: {controller}/{action}/`

Would happily pass that request to:

```
ActionResult GetUserList(int page, int pagesize)
```

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation - I can see the pattern now. Would have upvoted if I had enough reputation. Does that mean that I can have multiple method overloads for GetUserList method or I would have to leave just one?

Answer (score 0):

**/Controller/Index?var1=1&var2=2&var3=3**

```
ActionResult Index(int? var1, int? var2, int? var3)
{
    Return Content(
        String.Format("You entered: {0}, {1}, {2}", var1, var2, var3));
}
```

Result:

```
You entered: 1, 2, 3
```

**/Controller/Index?values=1&values=2&values=3**

```
ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<int> values)
{
    Return Content(
        String.Format("You entered: {0}, {1}, {2}", values[0], values[1], values[2]));
}
```

Result:

```
You entered: 1, 2, 3
```

I don't have any experience with code-behind, sorry. I'm curious, why do you use it?

Comment: Having multiple identically named query string parameters might be against convention I believe.

Comment: @LaserBeak, what do you mean by that. Can you please clarify. Will it work, but just would be frowned upon by a developers (as it goes against convention), or MVC framework will fail to parse such quiery string or to map it to a collection class.

Comment: @Rowan_Freeman Many thanks - didn't know that MVC allows to map a multiple parameters query string into a IEnumerable (@LaserBreak, I meant IEnumerable, not a collection in my previous comment)!